# In OpenGL, what's the best way to achieve a combined blend of primitives that don't all use the same shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, blend

Let's say I have a bunch of semi-transparent triangles that I want to render as part of the same scene, correctly blended in order of depth. If they all use the same shader (and same uniforms, OpenGL state etc), then all I have to do is sort them by depth before submitting to OpenGL and I can render them all with a single draw call.

But what do I do if I want to render some of the triangles using a different shader? I can't do a single draw call anymore because there's two shaders. Do I sort the two sets of triangles separately and render them one after the other? But that only works if the depth values of one of the sets happen to be all less than the depth values of the other set. What if the depth values of the two sets interleave? In the worst case, what if the two sets of triangles are perfectly interleaved, so that between every two consecutive triangles of one set there's a triangle from the other set? What do I do then? Do I have to do as many draw calls as there are triangles in order to get the right result? I would like to limit the number of draw calls since I've heard having many draw calls is bad for performance. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> In the worst case, what if the two sets of triangles are perfectly interleaved, so that between every two consecutive triangles of one set there's a triangle from the other set? What do I do then? Do I have to do as many draw calls as there are triangles in order to get the right result?

Yes, exactly so.

> I would like to limit the number of draw calls since I've heard having many draw calls is bad for performance.

Each draw call has a comparatively large overhead, sure. The less draw calls you can render your scene in, the faster it will be.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Sure, stop using different shaders. The whole "different shader" thing is just an assumption on your end, I haven't yet seen proof that it's actually needed. Between bindless textures, instanced drawing, SSBOs and plain ol atlases, you'd have to be rendering some pretty crazy triangles that you can't write just one shader for all of them.

Comment: If I have multiple different shaders from before that work fine on their own, it's a hassle having to combine them all into one, especially if they have different vertex input setups. Also, wouldn't I need to send some sort of data with the vertices to know what code to run for any given vertex and any given fragment? I'd also have to execute an additional branch for everything. But maybe the performance impact of those things is negligible?

Comment: Programming correctly is a hassle, up to you if it's worth it or not. I'm not sure if that part was a question or not. And sending more data is trivial compared to starting an entire new render pass. Branches probably aren't needed, use the entire GLSL library of functions to avoid them (additions and multiplications should help you avoid most of the branches, for example -- basic math).